# Post data are empty with php 7.1.32 and apache 2.4.39 on AWS

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services

i can't use post with php on AWS Linux. i changed enable_post_data_reading=On and post_max_size=8M, but i still can't use post data. Where could it be deactivated ?
I checked the php code on an other server and there the post data are not null.

Comment: Let's see the HTML form code and the PHP code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Have you accounted for this point noted in the [PHP documentation for $_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php):

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

Does the POST request you are submitting specify the above Content-Type header values?

Comment: i think so, it's a simple form with some text fields and radio buttons, nothing special

Comment: i can see the form data in google chrome developent tools

Answer (score 0):

i found the reason, and it's simple, but maybe anybody have the same problem, the action url was wrong action="http://...." instead of https://